# How to uninstall nginx (installed from source)?

Tags: nginx

I want to switch from a development version to a stable one.

I installed nginx from source with:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I tried `sudo make uninstall`  but it doesn't work.

How can I uninstall nginx?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/281920/how-to-uninstall-nginx-installed-from-source-on-centos (can't vote to close as dupe from another site, but voting to close as off topic)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To uninstall:

```
sudo rm -f -R /usr/local/nginx && rm -f /usr/local/sbin/nginx
```

Source:

http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/12/3/ubuntu-gutsy-installing-nginx-from-source

Answer (score 7):

Stop the service first:

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Our compiled-from-source files:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx /etc/default/nginx /usr/sbin/nginx* /usr/local/nginx /var/run/nginx.pid /var/log/nginx
```

The Debian scripts that came with the apt-get version:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/init.d/nginx /etc/logrotate.d/nginx /var/lib/update-rc.d/nginx
```

Your static content:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/www
```

Disable the startup daemon:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f nginx disable
```

source http://elinux.org/RPi_Nginx_Webserver

Comment: /etc/nginx is for installed package by one of the package-management utilities and can be removed using same tool.

Answer (score 0):

This help for me:

```
 make deinstall clean


 ;make===>  Deinstalling for nginx
 ===>   Deinstalling nginx-1.6.2_1,2
 Updating database digests format: 100%
 Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
 Deinstallation has been requested for the following 1 packages (of 0 packages in the universe):

 Installed packages to be REMOVED:
    nginx-1.6.2_1,2

 The operation will free 1 MiB.
 [1/1] Deinstalling nginx-1.6.2_1,2...
 [1/1] Deleting files for nginx-1.6.2_1,2: 100%
 ===>  Cleaning for nginx-1.6.2_1,2
```

And - done.

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /usr/ports/www/nginx
make deinstall
```

Comment: the OP din't say it's on a FreeBSD host